# I can't see upload files option within files tab in community whereas i can upload files through lightning view

Tags: customer-community, partner-communities

Upload files option is not visible on community whereas it is available on lightning view, i can even see files uploaded on lightning view on community

Answer (score 0):

When Profile-Based Chatter Rollout Feature is enabled for an organization and chatter is not enabled for a particular user profile, users with that profile will not be able to see the 'upload files' button under note and attachment section in community.

Enable Chatter for a particular User's profile

1. Log in as a Salesforce administrator.
2. From Setup, enter Profiles in the Quick Find box, then select Profiles.
3. For each of your existing custom user profiles:
    a) Click Edit.
    b) Select Enable Chatter.
4. Save your changes.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000322519&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1